# Can PayPal's CUSTOM variable be used on eBay?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I program with PHP and I'm familiar with getting data from PayPal's IPN. I need to send custom data to ebay and get it back when payment is made. For example, if sold 1 Widget on ebay and that widget has a stock number of 12345A, I receive data back from PayPal. I get things like customer's name, address, item name, etc. But, unless I include that stock number in my title, I don't see any way to get that data back from PayPal. I don't want to use ebay's limited title space for including my stock numbers. I realize I could do it if I had another database to store ebay's item numbers and cross reference them with my stock numbers, but I don't want to do that.

I have noticed that when data comes back from PayPal after an ebay sale, it includes the custom variable and that variable has a large number in assigned to it. I have no idea what that is. I've also tried using ebay's custom label feature that's found in Turbo Lister and Selling Manager Pro. I was hoping that would be sent back in PayPal's custom variable, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Did I miss something? What does PayPal's IPN have to do with eBay?

Comment: Yes, you must have missed something.  IPN is commonly used with eBay.  Paypal even has special variables specifically for auctions. No one seems to know how to send a custom variable, or why paypal is sending back a custom variable with a random number in it on auction sales.

Comment: Ebay doesn't provide any way that I have ever discovered to customise IPN data sent by PayPal. It provides its *own* API. @BernM's remark is perfectly sensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've discovered, it looks like it's some internal id number uniquely identifying each eBay order.  You can probably forget about specifying a value for this field as it isn't documented anywhere.

The best solution to your problem is to use the eBay API.  [GetSingleItem](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/Shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html) will return information about an item given the item id.

The `ItemSpecifics` list will contain any item specific data that the seller has entered about the product.  In my case, I added a custom field called *SKU* to the eBay item.  Just add itemspecifics to your include selector.  The call can be executed with a `GET` request:

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetSingleItem&IncludeSelector=ItemSpecifics&appid=YOURAPPID=515&ItemID=ITEMIDOFINTEREST
```

What you get back will contain those custom fields you added to your item:

```
   
    ..
    <ItemSpecifics>
    <NameValueList>
    <Name>MPN</Name>
    <Value>MyPartModelA</Value>
    </NameValueList>
    <NameValueList>
    <Name>SKU</Name>
    <Value>123-456</Value>
    </NameValueList>
    </ItemSpecifics>
    ..
```